# get data from html table with add row in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html table that added row in client side with Javascript, but cannot get all value of table with jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/aghababaei/8kw2p/

Here is my delete row button action:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("table.bordered").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            var mydata;
            //gets table

            $("#myTable tr").each(function (row, tr) {
                mydata = mydata
                    + $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text() + ' '
                    + $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text() + ' '
                    + $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text() + ' '
                    + $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text() + ' '
                    + '\n';
            });
            alert(mydata);
        });});
```

here is my html table:

```
        <table id="myTable" runat="server" class="bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>h1</td>
                <td>h2</td>
                <td>h3</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
```

There is a solution?

Comment: Do you mind making a jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: I don't know about jsfiddle, i just google it.

Comment: Could it be because you're overwriting mydata inside the .each loop instead of appending.

Comment: Solution for what? What is the problem? The JQuery code not working? if so what it should do?

Comment: something like this [http://jsfiddle.net/3yS3f/](http://jsfiddle.net/3yS3f/)?

Comment: Test without overwriting mydata, but same result and dialog is empty, i test many kind of get data, in static table no problem, but in dynamic table don't work..

Comment: @AbrahamUribe thanks, but if add new row in client side don't work.

Comment: it should work with dynamic elements as you use .on like this [http://jsfiddle.net/3yS3f/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/3yS3f/1/)

Comment: AbrahamUribe thanks, i try this.

Comment: a full code is here http://jsfiddle.net/aghababaei/8kw2p/ but don't work correctly, i have 2 jquery dialog that contain table and when row clicked row data insert in myTable, in delete action all myTable data get and show..
every things in my own project is correct except get and show data from myTable!